# Installation of ROS on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ros, installation, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I've just installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 15.10 "Wily Werewolf" on my VMWare Player.
I want to install the latest version of ROS (which is "Jade Turtle" I assume).
When going through the [installation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_install_of_ROS_Jade)
I've noticed already on step 1.2 the first problem.

> ROS Jade ONLY supports Trusty (14.04),
> Utopic (14.10) and Vivid (15.04) for
> debian packages.

As I am running 15.10, I assume, that ROS Jade doesn't support debian packages on my special system.
As I am not experienced with Ubuntu, I can only guess that the next steps of the tutorial won't for me as this is a pretty basic requirement for the system.

Does anyone has a easier-to-understand installing guide for me (I know that the tutorial I mentioned above is really simple already)?

Thanks in advance!
Che.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222708/installation-of-ros-on-ubuntu-15.10/) by [Che.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23353/che./) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2015-12-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, I've already found an answer in this board. http://answers.ros.org/question/220167/error-installing-ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-1510/

Greets.

---

Originally posted by [Che.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23353/che./) with karma: 48 on 2015-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-12-17**:
If you've answered your question, please mark your answer as correct so other ROS users can benefit from your question.

**Comment by [Che.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23353/che./) on 2015-12-18**:
Hi Luke, this is not possible.

> 10 points required to accept or unaccept your own answer

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-12-18**:
If you want to you can ask one of the moderators and they can probably do it for you.

**Comment by [Che.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23353/che./) on 2015-12-18**:
Now I've got the required points to set my own answer as solution ;)

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-12-18**:
Good for you!

**Comment by [Che.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23353/che./) on 2015-12-18**:
Indeed!!!!